# Border bottom menu when user active on hover

Tags: javascript, html, css, frontend

I made a menu fixed and sticky. Menu border bottom bar is active when the user hover mouse on it but what I want is when the user is on **source** section, previous **Call Data** section will still be active. Current and previous sections, both will be active. Can someone help me with this?

see the images of the menu please,

[Call Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yJD5d.png)
[Source](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AQVaV.png)

```
<div class="nav" id="myNav">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#call-data">Call Data</a></li>
        <li><a href="#source">Source</a></li>
        <li><a href="#lead">Lead</a></li>
        <li><a href="#address">Address</a></li>
        <li><a href="#motivation">Motivation</a></li>
        <li><a href="#property">Property</a></li>
        <li><a href="#visit">Visit</a></li>
        <li><a href="#finish">Finish</a></li>
    </ul>
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">
        <i class="fa fa-bars"></i></a>
</div>
```

and css here,

```
ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}

.nav {
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: white;
    position: -webkit-sticky;
    /* Safari */
    position: -moz-sticky;
    /* firefox */
    z-index: 5;
}

.nav a {
    float: left;
    display: block;
    color: black;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 24px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 17px;
}

.nav a:hover {
    color: green;
    border-bottom: 3px solid green;
}

.nav a.active {
    color: green;
    border-bottom: 3px solid green;
}

.nav .icon {
    display: none;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1210px) {
    .nav a:not(:first-child) {
        display: none;
    }
    .nav a.icon {
        float: right;
        display: block;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1210px) {
    .nav.responsive {
        position: sticky;
        top: 0;
        overflow: hidden;
        background-color: white;
        position: -webkit-sticky;
        /* Safari */
        position: -moz-sticky;
        /* Safari */
        z-index: 5;
        opacity: 0.9;
    }
    .nav.responsive .icon {
        position: absolute;
        right: 0;
        top: 0;
    }
    .nav.responsive a {
        float: none;
        display: block;
        text-align: left;
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you mean that if you hover on Source, and currently your are on Call Data they both should have green border-bottom?

Comment: @DaniyalLukmanov Yes, exactly. And so on, When I hover on other sections, all other sections before the current section will be active.

Comment: But that doesn't make any sense. 'Active' means - you're on that page. You can only apply the same style to active link and the one that you hover over (navbar links I mean).

Comment: or do I have to use something else than 'active'?

Comment: Why don't you just add active to the previous element too then?

Comment: @Mark_Ed I added, it shows only first element when active and removed after because this was not I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

You could try with a css siblings selector, e.g.:

```
li > a[href="#source"]:hover ~ li > a[href="#call-data"]{
  color: green;
    border-bottom: 3px solid green;
}
```

if this doesn't work you can use jquery, with the good old $('#element').hover(); method.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
.nav a:visited {
    color: green;
    border-bottom: 3px solid green;
}
```

Let me know if you have any doubt.